# Extract words from a file and put them into a `std::vector` of `std::array<string,4>`

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, while-loop

The following is the file(ka.txt) from which I want to read lines :-

```
ASD|BSD|CSdsa|ood
fmads|aok|pdski
kdijf|okmdsomf|opkasd|okd
asdas
kamkd|aoda|kked|ok
```

The following is the code that I've written to put this data into a vector of std::array<std::string, 4>.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main(){
        std::fstream file("ka.txt");
        std::vector<std::array<std::string, 4>> darr; darr.reserve(5);
        std::array<std::string, 4> istd;
        std::string * line = new std::string; std::string * word = new std::string;
        while(std::getline(file, *line)){
                std::stringstream ss(*line);
                int per = 0;
                while(!ss.eof()){
                        std::getline(ss, *&istd[per], '|');
                        per++;
                }       
                darr.emplace_back(istd);
        }       
        file.close();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < darr.size(); i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                        std::cout << darr[i][j] << "\t";
                }       
                std::cout << "\n";
        }       
  
        return 0;       
}
```

Basically, I have a vector which has `std::array`'s and each `std::array` is of size 4. So I am reading the data from the file with `|` delimiter. And I want to store each element in every row of the text file as a `std::array`. And storing these `std::array`s in one vector. Also, if one row has 4 elements separated by `|`, then there should be four elements in the `std::array`. If there is only one element in the row, then there should be only one element in the `std::array`
So when I run this code I get the following output:-

```
ASD BSD CSdsa   ood 
fmads   aok pdski       
kdijf   okmdsomf    opkasd  okd 
asdas       opkasd  okd 
kamkd   aoda    kked    ok
```

So, the fourth row has a wrong `std::array` since it should only have one element, but instead it should have only one. How can I achieve this?

Also, I think the probable problem is in the `while` loop which begins at line 12 of the code.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to be using `new` in this program whatsoever.

Comment: `std::string line, word;` -- That's all you need to do.

Comment: Also `*&istd[per]` can be simply `istd[per]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the array `istd` is used without initializing, so data from previous lines remains when no data is read there.

```
std::array<std::string, 4> istd;
```

should be after

```
while(std::getline(file, *line)){
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested the below code. Usage of istd made it to show wrong output as it remembers the previous values. I changed it to use vector instead of array.
As pointed by Paul,we don't need to use new for string. So removed it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main(){
        std::fstream file("file.txt");
        vector<vector<string>> darr;
        std::string  line,word;
        while(std::getline(file, line))
        {
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            vector<string> temp;
            string str;
            while(!ss.eof())
            {
                std::getline(ss, str, '|');
                temp.push_back(str);
            }
            darr.emplace_back(temp);
        }
        file.close();
        for(int i = 0; i < darr.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    std::cout << darr[i][j] << " ";
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I also have a shortened version of the same code incase if you dont want to store.

```
int main(){
        std::fstream file("file.txt");
        std::string  line,word;
        while(std::getline(file, line))
        {
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            vector<string> temp;
            string str;
            while(!ss.eof())
            {
                std::getline(ss, str, '|');
                std::cout << str << " ";
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        file.close();
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ASD BSD CSdsa ood 
fmads aok pdski  
kdijf okmdsomf opkasd okd 
asdas    
kamkd aoda kked ok
```

Comment: `std::string * line = new std::string; std::string * word = new std::string;` -- You should at least address this issue.

Comment: Edited the post.